# sending mail at user assigned time and updating status in database in rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to `send mail` at `remind_at` time of each stage. i am using `whenever gem` to schedule task. There are `user` model that contains `email` of multiple user with role manager, and each manager has `one_to_many` association with `project` and project `has one_to_many` association with `stage`.

while sending email to each user i want to update attribute `mail_status` of stage and mail subject change to `stage.name` for each user. how can i achieve such goal??

stage.rb

```
def check_project_activity
  current_date = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_s
  @stages = Stage.all
  @stages.each do |stage|
    ProjectMailer.activity_reminder(stage).deliver and stage.mail_status = true and stage.save! if stage.remind_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_s == current_date
  end
end
```

schedule.rb

```
  every 1.day, at: '4:30 am' do
    runner 'stage.project_activity_check'
  end
```

activity_mailer.rb

```
  def activity_reminder(stage)
    @stage = stage
      mail(:to =>  User.joins(projects: :stages).where(role: 'manager', stages: { remind_at: Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }).pluck(:email), :subject => "activity reminder " + stage.name)
  end
```

i took reference from this post - [Sending emails on user-selected dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934896/sending-emails-on-user-selected-dates)

but my implementation is not working.

Here is code that i used but problem is it sends email once to all user but i want dynamic change is email subjet according to user and also template body changes-

activity_reminder.rb

```
desc 'activity reminder email'
task activity_reminder_email: :environment do
  ProjectMailer.activity_reminder(self).deliver!
end
```

project_mailer.rb

```
  def activity_reminder(stage)
    @stage = stage
      mail(:to =>  User.joins(projects: :stages).where(role: 'manager', stages: { remind_at: Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }).pluck(:email), :subject => "Project Activity Remainder")
  end
```

schedule.rb

```
  every 1.day, at: '4:30 am' do
    rake 'activity_reminder_email'
  end
```

it works fine but i want email subject as `stage.name` to be according to each user and also  it should loop though each task and update `stage.email_status` for executed task.

Comment: Why your implementation isn't working?

Comment: @SebastianPalma i followed the reference but executing ```Stage.last.check_project_activity``` resulted error - ```private method `check_project_activity' called for ```. but without writing logic in model. using rake task scheduler, works.  it sends one to all target user email once, i want dynamic changes in email template and email subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do some changes:

- <strike>You're formatting the `remind_at` values as a stringified version of a Y-m-d date, in that case, you could just compare them as dates. `to_date` is enough.</strike>
- Instead of selecting everything and filtering then, you can filter the rows within your SQL query; cast the remind_at to date and use your RDBMS function to get the current date, after that the comparison remains the same.
- Left it untouched, but you could probably select the exact columns you're using in your query. This is often preferred so you get what you just need, nothing more, nothing less.
- Prefer `&&` over `and`, since they don't have the same precedence (`&&` being higher), which may led to inconsistences in your code (this isn't Python).
- You can use `update` instead of a two-lines assignment.

```
def check_project_activity
  Stage.where('remind_at::date = CURRENT_DATE').each do |stage|
    ProjectMailer.activity_reminder(stage).deliver
    stage.update(mail_status: true)
  end
end
```

`remind_at::date = CURRENT_DATE` is PostgreSQL specific, but it can be easily adapted.

Comment: still same error i get as earlier, i updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, that's because the visibility of your `check_project_activity` is private, in such case you can do; or to declare the method as public or to use `send(:check_project_activity)` on the object rather than `check_project_activity`.

Comment: HI thanks it worked. now the only problem is in mailer method it send email to multiple times